# Arrange nodes under a closed element - XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping, muenchian-grouping

So I have this XML:

```
<Main>
 <TB>
    --> some elements - not relevant
   <Area>
     <Type>A</Type>
     <Street>
       <Position>5</Position>
       <House>

       --> some elements

       </House>
     </Street>
     <Street>
       <Position>5</Position>
       <Block>

       --> some elements

       </Block>
     </Street>
     <Street>
       <Position>6</Position>
       <House>

       --> some elements

       </House>
     </Street>
     <Street>
       <Position>6</Position>
       <Block>

       --> some elements

       </Block>
     </Street>
   </Area>
   <Area>
    <Type>B</Type>
   --> same structure but with several repetitions of Position 7 and 8.

   </Area>
 </TB>
</Main>
```

And I want to order it like that:

```
<Area>
   <Type>A</Type>
     <Street>
       <Position>5</Position>
       <House>

       --> some elements

       </House>
       <Block>

       --> some elements

       </Block>
     </Street>
     <Street>
       <Position>6</Position>
       <House>

       --> some elements

       </House>
       <Block>

       --> some elements

       </Block>
     </Street>
   </Area>
   <Area>
     <Type>B</Type>
   --> same structure for Position 7 and 8.

   </Area>
```

And I am using this XSLT to transform it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="streetByPosition" match="Street" use="Position" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- for the first Street in each Position -->
  <xsl:template match="Street[generate-id() =
                            generate-id(key('streetByPosition', Position)[1])]">
    <Street>
      <!-- copy in the Position element once only -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Position" />
      <!-- copy in all sub-elements except Position from all matching Streets-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="
            key('streetByPosition', Position)/*[not(self::Position)]" />
    </Street>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ignore all other Street elements -->
  <xsl:template match="Street" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The ordering works completely fine.
But if I have repetitive `Position` numbers in different `Type` then I get all the `House`s and `Block`s arranged in the first `Type` where I had the repetitive `Position` number. 
For example:

```
<Area>
         <Type>A</Type>
         <Street>
           <Position>5</Position>
           <House>

           --> some elements

           </House>
         </Street>
         <Street>
           <Position>5</Position>
           <Block>

           --> some elements

           </Block>
         </Street>
....
<Area>
     <Type>B</Type>
     <Street>
       <Position>5</Position>
       <House>

       --> some elements

       </House>
     </Street>
```

Then the elements under `Position 5` in `Type B` will be moved from there to under `Position 5` in `TypeA`. And I don't want that. I want the Houses and Blocks to be arranged but stay in their own types and areas.

Can anyone provide me with solution of how do I have to change my XSLT in order to fix this?

P.S. the names of the XML tags were changed for simplification reasons. And I cannot use xslt-2.0 because my editor doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to you will need a compound key, which will be a concatenation of all values that identify your group, in your case the **Type** (of the parent element), and the **Position**

```
<xsl:key name="streetByPosition" match="Street" use="concat(../Type, '|', Position)" />
```

You can then use the key in the normal way

```
key('streetByPosition', concat(../Type, '|', Position))
```

Try the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="streetByPosition" match="Street" use="concat(../Type, '|', Position)" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- for the first Street in each Position -->
  <xsl:template match="Street[generate-id() =
                            generate-id(key('streetByPosition', concat(../Type, '|', Position))[1])]">
    <Street>
      <!-- copy in the Position element once only -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Position" />
      <!-- copy in all sub-elements except Position from all matching Streets-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="
            key('streetByPosition', concat(../Type, '|', Position))/*[not(self::Position)]" />
    </Street>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ignore all other Street elements -->
  <xsl:template match="Street" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only thing to note is that the 'pipe' character in the concatenation can be any character you like, just as long as it does not occur in either of the **Type** and **Position** elements, to ensure two different combination of such elements do not result in the same key.